# What were the humans in the tanks used for?

Tags: the-puppet-masters

When the Nivens visit the Titanian ship, they come across a tank full of humans who were alive. What were the slugs using them for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The humans were test subjects who had a disease dangerous to the slugs (the true threat) which had taken over the Titanians (the slugs current host/carrier) called Nine Day Fever.

- The Titanians were using them in an effort to find a cure for the disease which kills the slugs faster than their hosts.
- This gives the book's protagonists, Sam, Mary and the Old Man the idea of spreading the disease among the human populace to stop the invasion from spreading as quickly.
- The threat of the slugs already had a good foothold so spreading the disease would only slow the slug advance but would give humanity a fighting chance at survival.

Comment: Hmm, that implies that the slugs were fully aware of the nine-day fever before they invaded and had had 20 years to find a cure for it. When Andrew Niven is infected, his master states something along the lines of "we won't make the same mistake again", a statement which now sounds rather hollow.

Comment: Humans aren't the only trash-talking life-forms out there...